# How to extend battery life on custom pi laptop

Tags: electronics, battery

So I'm trying to make a pi laptop based on [this project](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-and-Arduino-Laptop/) with a few differences:

- I use [this display](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_%28B%29) instead of [this](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_LCD_for_Pi)
- Technically, I'm using 18650 cells, but [at a slightly reduced
  capacity](https://www.adafruit.com/product/353)
- No Arduinos on my laptop
- Keyboard on my laptop is plugged into USB port on the Pi while his is, along with trackpad and USB hub is soldered to the test pins on the Pi.

The maker of the original mentions getting around 4.5 hours on his laptop and despite the small differences in the capacities of the batteries used (7200-6600 = 600mAh), although considering how much fewer current consuming devices there are on my laptop I though I should get something at least close to that time. I'm getting a meager 2.5 to 2.8 hours of light use out of mine at the moment. Mostly programming through a console or text editor plus compiling as I'm using this to study programming.

I'm wondering if the fact that his USB devices are soldered to the test pins might have something to do with that. If not, I think it's still something I'm doing wrong on my end. What optimizations or improvements can I make to improve battery life.

Comment: it is probably related to your choice of the LCD display .... the HDMI controler and the USB controller probably make the difference .... the website has no spec sheet for that display (could not find any)